# Laravel 5.2 view in register a provider

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, package

i have installed the chat package:
https://github.com/dazzz1er/confer

Unfortunately i get an error when i try to publish it. Here is the error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::composer()

Thanks !

Comment: Please refer to this issue https://github.com/dazzz1er/confer/issues/20

Answer (score 1):

As correctly pointed out by @curious_coder `confer` is not compatible with Laravel 5.2 yet. Please keep an on the open [Laravel 5.2 issue on Github](https://github.com/dazzz1er/confer/issues/20) and/or ask the author of this package for updates.